# UPS API integration- multiple accounts

Tags: integration, ups, ups-api

I'm trying to integrate with UPS API, but would like to integrate with different UPS accounts based on various different rules that span over multiple portals.

Below mentioned are some of the access information to post ship-confirm-request

```
<AccessRequest xml:lang="en-US">
    <AccessLicenseNumber>132</AccessLicenseNumber>
    <UserId>XXX</UserId>
    <Password>XXX</Password>
</AccessRequest>

<Shipper>
        <ShipperNumber>xxx</ShipperNumber>
</Shipper>
```

Reading the UPS documentation, i see that

```
Shipper's six digit account number. Must be associated with the UserId specified in the AccessRequest XML
```

**My Question**
To integrate with multiple accounts do i have to request for Shipper account number and  info (below), for every single UPS account we have to integrate with?

```
<AccessRequest xml:lang="en-US">
        <AccessLicenseNumber>132</AccessLicenseNumber>
        <UserId>XXX</UserId>
        <Password>XXX</Password>
    </AccessRequest>
```

Or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Although this doesn't programmatically solve your problem, you're definitely able to have multiple UPS accounts connected to a Shippo account and just define your rules on when to use specific UPS accounts through Shippo's api. https://goshippo.com/docs/carrier-accounts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spoke to the tech support at UPS, 
There are two ways to handle multiple accounts.

- Create access info at "https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit/" for all accounts. (tedious)
- Create access-keys at https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit/ Then
  add all your related accounts to this account and you should be able 
  to use the same info below and just vary your shipper account number.

> ```
> <AccessRequest xml:lang="en-US">
>     <AccessLicenseNumber>132</AccessLicenseNumber>
>     <UserId>XXX</UserId>
>     <Password>XXX</Password>
> </AccessRequest>
> ```

Comment: UPS is assigning no new access keys after June 5, 2023; existing keys will be disabled June 2024.

Answer (score 0):

You have to request different times for the information. It is quite quick with 4 steps involved (see the [guide to request UPS API credentials](http://support.postmen.com/article/12-ups-developer-guide-api-credentials))

Comment: The link doesn't work. Can you please check @Andrew